# What is the proper way to remove specific string in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm making a program that adding/removing registered plate numbers but I`m having a trouble when I remove a specific plate number. Here is some parts of my code.

```
ArrayList<String> PlateNumber = new ArrayList<String>(10);

System.out.println("Enter your Plate Number : ");
Scanner pn = new Scanner(System.in);
String PlateNumberxx = pn.nextLine();

System.out.println("Log in / Log out: ");
Scanner YoN = new Scanner(System.in);
String des = YoN.nextLine();

if(des.equals("log in")) {
    PlateNumber.add(PlateNumberxx);
}

if(des.equals("log out")){
    PlateNumber.remove(PlateNumberxx);
    System.out.println("Time log out : " + PlateNumberxx + " " + d);
}
```

It doesnt remove what I enter in scanner. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Don't create several scanners, just create one associated with `System.in` and keep reading from it.

Comment: Where did you add the element to the list?

Comment: I edited my question, you can check it again.

Comment: As @sergiu commented, there's nothing to remove since you haven't added anything into your list...

Comment: Nothing obvious is jumping out.  Have you tried stepping through the code and checking to make sure that the value you're trying to remove is actually in the array and matches exactly?

Comment: This code fragments are working fine for me. Please post short but full code example which we could use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `des` can't equal both "log in" and "log out" at the same time, and you only get a value from input once to test... Is this your actual code that you're running?

Comment: @jgitter Yes, I checked it already but it doesnt remove what I type.

Comment: Provide example of what you type, what is already in your ArrayList, and how you check that `remove` doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe PlateNumberXX has got some whitespace or new line character. Try to invoke a trim on PlateNumberXX before passing it to remove

Comment: @Pshemo ex. I typed "ako 900" > log in. (Loop from the top). I type "ako 900" once again > log out but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you expecting this ArrayList to maintain the data between separate runs of your program? I.e., you run it once, and log in a plate number. Then, you run the program again, and log out that plate number?

Comment: Until you put some effort and post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we could use to reproduce your problem I am voting to put this question on hold. Let me know when you update your question so I could withdraw my vote.

Comment: Ok, I will work for it. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite how your list is being initialised when you are trying to remove elements, I'm not sure. I would guess that this is where your problem may lie.

However, in order to remove elements, your code is working.

Here it is with an element added to this list. I print out what's in the list before and after it is removed.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<String> plateNumber = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    plateNumber.add("123");

    System.out.println("Plate Numbers to begin with: " + plateNumber.toString());

    System.out.println("Enter your Plate Number : ");
    final Scanner pn = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String plateNumberxx = pn.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Log in / Log out: ");
    final Scanner YoN = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String des = YoN.nextLine();

    if(des.equals("log in")) {
        plateNumber.add(plateNumberxx);
    }

    if(des.equals("log out")){
        plateNumber.remove(plateNumberxx);
        System.out.println("Time log out : " + plateNumberxx + " ");
        System.out.println("Plate Numbers after removal: " + plateNumber.toString());
    }
}
```

And the output I got was this:

> Plate Numbers to begin with: [123]
>
> Enter your Plate Number :
>
> 123
>
> Log in / Log out:
>
> log out
>
> Time log out : 123
>
> Plate Numbers after removal: []

Comment: what if i entered 3 plate numbers, then the user typed the 2nd plate number to log out. does the remove(); is applicable?

Comment: Well, currently the code doesn't do that, you'd need a loop for that. Run you loop enough times (eternally?) to allow you to add the multiple plate numbers, then when you remove one it should work just fine.

Comment: [Here's an example on ideone](https://ideone.com/1dC5qh) with an eternal loop and a break to allow you to remove a single element before the application exits. I don't know what your loop termination conditions would be since this isn't in your question.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to remove a value from an arraylist, dont use the method ArrayList.remove(the value), but find out what index it is at, and delete that index, or in some cases all the indexes the value exists at.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Random Content
    list.add("Apple");
    list.add("Banana");
    list.add("Plum");
    list.add("Orange");
    list.add("Apple");
    list.add("Pineapple");
    list.add("Peach");
    list.add("Plum");

    // Remove a value
    {
        String remove = "Apple";

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(remove)){
                list.remove(i);

                /*
                 * When we remove a value we have to iterate 1 index backwards,
                 * because the next value in the list is now shifted one index,
                 * so the list[i+1] becomes the new list[i], and in case it is the
                 * same value we have to check the new list[i] in addition, otherwise
                 * if we had two "Apple"s in a row, only the first 1 would get removed.
                 */

                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use .remove() ?

Comment: Because the .remove() function compares the objects with the == comparator, which does not work with objects, because with objects it only compares the object references, not the object values. For example: String s1 = "test"; String s2 = "test"; and then s1 == s2 will give false, since it is two different references to two different objects. Therfore i used the .equals() (Overwritten in the java.lang.String class, inherited from java.lang.Object class. The one in hte object class checks for reference equality) comparator in the code, because it compares the string value.

Comment: What makes you think that? I'm looking at the 1.6.0_31 source code for ArrayList, and it's clearly using .equals() . Line 423: if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {

Comment: What if I dont know the index of the element, Ex. I tpyed 3 plate numbers, then the 2nd plate number wants to log out. How do I remove that 2nd plate number w/o knowing what the index of it?

Comment: The `remove` method's contract is to compare with `equals`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Possibly you are confused by the fact that there can be problems with a `Collection<Integer> coll` and `coll.remove(i)`, depending on the type of `i` and boxing and unboxing (you could call the wrong `remove` overload).